# Easy Java 2D Array Maze Game

Tags: java, arrays

I'm working on a maze game for a 2D array project. So far I have managed to make a randomized game board. Each time the program is run, the game board is randomized. The goal is to get 'P' (player) from the top right corner to 'E' (end) bottom left corner while avoiding 'X' and '*'. I need help making a method which allows the player to input Up, Down, Right, Left and make P move. This is what I have so far:

```
public class MazeGame {
//Declare scanner to allow user to input directional commands
Scanner move = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Call methods
    Game_Beginning();
    Game_Board();     
}

//Intro to the game
public static void Game_Beginning(){
           System.out.println("This is your game board:");
    System.out.println("-------------------------------");
}

//Game Board
public static void Game_Board(){
    //Declare new array, maze 10x10
    char maze[][] = new char[10][10];

    //Randomly print the obstacles in the maze.
    for (int i = 0; i < maze.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < maze.length; j++){
            double random = Math.random();
            if (random <= .05){
                maze[i][j] = '*';
            }
            else if (random > .06 && random <= .15){
                maze[i][j] = 'X';
            }
            else{
                maze[i][j] = '.';
            }
            maze[0][0] = 'P';
            maze[9][9] = 'E';
            System.out.print(maze[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }


}

/**
 *  Add a method called "makePMove." Define char right, char left and so on
 */
public static void makeMove(){
    int row;
    int col;
    System.out.print("Enter your move (Up-Down-Left-Right): ");

}
```

}

Comment: You should save the position of `P`, and then have a `move()` method that tests the direction they entered. Remember to check if the index is out of bounds, and return appropriately.

Comment: [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) state that methods should not begin with a capital letter and should be verbs (or at least begin with a verb). Also, the underscore is usually only used for naming a constant - not in a method name.

Comment: Since your board is generated purely at random there is no guarantee that the maze is solvable. You should consider writing some logic to verify that the maze can be solved and to generate a new one if it is not possible to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a loop and recognize user commands. So you can add something like this after your Game_Board() method

```
while (true) {

        String playerInput = move.next();
        switch (playerInput) {
            case "u" :
                System.out.println("User command is 'up'");
                break;
            case "d" :
                System.out.println("User command is 'down'");
                break;
            case "l" :
                System.out.println("User command is 'left'");
                break;
            case "r" :
                System.out.println("User command is 'right'");
                break;
            case "e" :
                System.out.println("User command is 'exit'");
                break;
            case "y" :
                System.out.println("User command is 'yes'");
                break;
            case "n" :
                System.out.println("User command is 'no'");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Unknown command '" + playerInput + "'!");
        }
    }
```

Then once you know what is the required direction you need:
1. Identify target position in your array/board.
2. Validate if movement to target position is allowed by your rules
3. If movement is allowed:
3.1. Put 'P' into target posotion
3.2. Put '.' into previous position of 'P'

Also make sure that you have implemented expected behaviour for user to exit.